# Option required in multiple select

Tags: html, html-select

I have a select like this :

```
<select name="cars" multiple>
  <option value="volvo" selected>Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

I would like the option "Volvo" selected by default and required, but the user can unselect it if he wants. I would like that the user would not be able to unselect it.

This select is generated with PHP, so I can add an hidden field, but I want the user to know that this option is required. How can I do that?

Comment: If it's always required, why make it part of the select to begin with?

Comment: Because it can change with the user, and I want the user to know that this option will always be sent

Comment: Are you saying that no matter which option is selected, "volvo" should also always be part of the final select's value?

Comment: I dont understand why its an selectable option then, but if you want to keep it, you could just give the volvo a classname and a permanent `background-color: lightgrey;` if they user changes the selection volvo will seem like its selected.

Comment: You could set it as a hidden field instead. Otherwise you're probably bound to a JavaScript solution.